# Union order of SQL Server statements affected by parameterisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, union

Dealing with some legacy code and in trying to get a poorly designed database to display what we want I did a self-union on a table to display an intersection of records in a certain order - simplified e.g.

```
SET @setOfRecords = 1234
SET @subsetOfRecords = 4567 

--Set A
SELECT * 
FROM results
WHERE 
    resultSet = @setOfRecords AND
    resultSubset = 4567

UNION

--Set B
SELECT * 
FROM results
WHERE 
    resultSet = @setOfRecords AND
    resultSubset <> 4567
```

Displays correctly, i.e.

```
Set A
Set B
```

However, if I parametrise the subset id this order is reversed - e.g.

```
SET @setOfRecords = 1234
SET @subsetOfRecords = 4567 

--Set A
SELECT * 
FROM results
WHERE 
    resultSet = @setOfRecords AND
    resultSubset = @subsetOfRecords

UNION

--Set B
SELECT * 
FROM results
WHERE 
    resultSet = @setOfRecords AND
    resultSubset <> @subsetOfRecords
```

Displays incorrectly, i.e.

```
Set B
Set A
```

I am aware that this is not an ideal method, however other constraints have lead to the necessity of this implementation.  My question is purely on why the ordering is affected by parametrisation on the resultSubset ID.

Any ideas?  Running on SQL Server 2008.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect any specific order? You haven't included an `ORDER BY` clause. Therefore SQL Server is free to return the rows in any order it deems most efficient.

If you want a predictable order, include an `ORDER BY` clause. If you don't include one, you're telling SQL Server that you don't care about order.

In this case you can compare the actual execution plans and you will probably find a difference in at least one sort operator. This could be due to a variety of reasons, including parameter sniffing, statistics, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look at the execution plan.

Comment: @PaulCoghill - you *will* need to add an `ORDER BY` to get it to behave consistently (even if you can fudge the execution plan now, any change (service pack, data volumes, phase of the moon) might change the plan again.

Comment: @PaulCoghill also the sort may be introduced in different ways because you're using `UNION` (which filters out duplicates in both sets). If you don't need to weed out duplicates, you will probably see different behavior with `UNION ALL` instead. But if you want to rely on a consistent ordering, as several people have said now, you need an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The order of results are not guaranteed unless you add an ORDER BY clause. Can you add a column to indicate the set and order on it?

Update per your comment, are you saying you couldn't do something like this?

```
SET @setOfRecords = 1234
SET @subsetOfRecords = 4567 

--Set A
SELECT * 
FROM (
    select 'A' as TheSet, results.*
    from results) A
WHERE 
    resultSet = @setOfRecords AND
    resultSubset = @subsetOfRecords

UNION

--Set B
SELECT * 
FROM (
    select 'B' as TheSet, results.*
    from results) B
WHERE 
    resultSet = @setOfRecords AND
    resultSubset <> @subsetOfRecords

ORDER BY TheSet
```

Comment: I'm afraid not in this case, adding a column would have been ideal but given the circumstances we just needed the data out - was just surprised that the parametrisation caused this change.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, that would indeed have worked.  Thanks for that, don't know why I didn't think of that - not enough caffeine today!  I was mostly interested as to why this made a difference at all.  I didn't think the parametrisation would have mattered.

Comment: You can even do it the other way - add the column as part of the `SELECT` clauses that define the union, then wrap it all into a subselect that *doesn't* select the `TheSet` column in the final `SELECT` clause, but *does* use it in the outer `ORDER BY` - so the column list of the result doesn't change.